# Is it possible to unflag a post?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged a post as being off-topic.  I've since changed my mind and I wish to unflag the post.  Is this possible?  Or do I just have to wait for a moderator to either accept or reject the flag?

Comment: There is no un-flag option - it is flagged to 3 of the GIS-SE moderators who then can take action - in your case it was made a community wiki - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts - I pref this to closing questions.

Comment: Thanks Mapperz.

Comment: @Mapperz, Thanks for replying.  (1) Please post your comment as an answer so the SE team doesn't later get down on us for leaving meta questions unanswered. (2) I'm concerned your last remark might leave some misimpressions with some readers, so please permit me to clarify a point I know you understand well. CW has a specific purpose (intended to be used rarely): it's not a dumping ground for questions that ought to be closed.

Comment: I closed questions when needed - GIS is a broad subject there has to be some leeway and Community Wiki can be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no un-flag option** - it is flagged to 3 of the GIS-SE moderators who then can take action - in your case it was made a community wiki - [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)